# Select option onchange with ejs only works for array[0]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I display different text based on the select option it works for the first element but id doesnt work for other element in the iteration

index.ejs

```
<select class="pay_method">
                                                                        <option selected>Selelct bank</option>
                                                                        <option value="1"></option>
                                                                        <option value="2"></option>
                                                                        <option value="3"></option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                    <div class="paymentMethod p1">
                                                                        <p>Acc.</p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="paymentMethod p2">
                                                                        <p>Acc.</p>
                                                                    </div>
```

index.js

```
$(".pay_method").change(function () {
    $('.paymentMethod').slideUp();
    switch ($('.pay_method :selected').val()) {
        case '1':
            $('.p1').slideDown();
            break;
        case '2':
            $('.p2').slideDown();
            break;
    }
});
```

Make onchange works on all element

Answer (score 0):

Could you check, what is your jquery version used? It could be related to that, try with 1.6.4 f.e.

Comment: Please use comments to ask for information, post an answer when you are answering

Comment: please help here i have been stuck for weeks